# create a log in the MVC system

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a problem to create a log in the MVC system.

My controller accesses the model and renders the view ... until this point all right.

now comes the doubt
My controller accesses the model of the blog and I get the id of the post and the data are encapsulated in the controller class, how could I do to create a system log with the id of the page visited outside the controller?

thank you

Comment: Are you using any particular framework?

Comment: no
I'm developing my own

Answer (score 0):

You can write the log to a file:

```
$log_file_path = "/path/log.txt";
$fh = fopen($log_file_path, 'a'); // 'a' for append to the file

$log_text = "Visited Page " . $page_id . "\n"; // This is the line to appear in the log file

fwrite($fh, $log_text);
fclose($fh); // Make sure to close the file
```

Comment: I can not have been specific ...
My application runs the controller, the controller renders the view, and after processing the application precido I create a log with the statistical data:
date, data browser, ip, and id of the page visited

/ / Controller processing and rendering
$ app-> controller ()
/ / Create the log with the ID page of the controller
$ app-> write_stats ()

Comment: Then I'm sorry I'm having trouble understanding what the actual problem is... What are you trying to achieve that you are having problems with?

Comment: suppose I have a blog at MVC ...
1. the application executes the controller and it runs the model.
controller contains the data from post-> array (id, title, text)
Two. The controller renders the page with the data model.
3. when the application is complete, you must create a log of user data (parents, browser, ip, time processing system, **and the ID of the page that is in the controller**)

in short, when the system finishes the process, you must create a report with information and user ID of the page so I can analyze the process of each page

was easier to understand?
thank you :)

Comment: OK, but where are you having trouble? If you put the code above in the Controller class then you have access to the ID of the page.